# In how many ways can we put five different fruits into three different bowls? Note that the bowls may be empty

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> In how many ways can we put five different fruits into three different bowls? Note that the bowls may be empty.

Using permutations I have figured out the number of ways if you fill all three bowls with one, but I am not able to incorporate the empty bowls as well.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Are the bowls different?

Comment: @Parcly Taxel, Yes the bowls are

Answer (score 3):

Consider the number of choices for each fruit:  there are three bowls where you can place that fruit.  So for all five fruits, there are a total of $3^5 = 243$ outcomes.

Comment: What about the empty bowls ?

Comment: @callculus: This accounts for them!  We count the mappings from the fruits to the bowls (both fruits and bowls are distinct individuals).  An empty bowl corresponds to a mapping that is not onto (surjective).  Of course we cannot have all three bowls empty (fruits have to go into a least one of the bowls).

Comment: @hardmath Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $F=${$A,B,C,D,E$} be the fruits.

Consider the following string

$$ABCDE||$$

permutating this you'll get the number that you're looking for: $\frac{7!}{2!}$

---

The string "$ABCDE||$" means all the fruits in the first bowl. And "$A|B|CDE$" means $A$ in the first, $B$ in the second and $C,D,E$ in the latter

Comment: This introduces double counting because you consider the order of fruits within a bowl as being different solutions.

Comment: Now you have eliminated some choices, because $A$ must never appear in a bowl later than the other fruits.

Comment: Why? You can consider the permutation "BCDEA||"

Comment: Okay, so "BCDEA||" and "ABCDE||" both put all the fruits in the first bowl.  You count this twice?  But my objection about eliminating some choices was based on your figure $\binom{7}{2}$, which you have now replaced by $7!/2!$.  In any case both values are incorrect.

Comment: Yes, in this way they are counted as different. I replaced $\binom{7}{2}$, that was my error.